# How to display or hide JSON data on a page based on a string value?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a form which has an Email field.  There is also an option to hide or show email address on a web page depending on which radio button was selected ("YES" or "No").

So, when `exclude_email="No"` the email should not be displayed. I know it is a conditional statement, but I am lost here...

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var people = [];

    $.getJSON('data2.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.name + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.title + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.company + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + "<div style=\"text-align:center\">" + f.email + "</div>" + "</td>" + "<td>" + "<div style=\"text-align:center\">" + f.comment + "</div>" + "</td>" + "</tr>"
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

        if (f.exclude_email == "No")
          this.hide(email);
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you also post the HTML code for your radio button? Just a guess but I think you are probably not getting the correct value for that radio button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it inline when building the string.

```
$(function() {
    var people = [];
    $.getJSON('data2.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = "" + "" + 
                f.name + "" + "" + 
                f.title + "" + "" + 
                f.company + "" + "" + "" + 
                (f.exclude_email == "No" ? '' : f.email) + "" + "" + "" + "" +
                f.comment + "" + "" + ""

            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
            if (f.exclude_email == "No") this.hide(email);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked! Thank you!

$(function() {

var people = [];

$.getJSON('data2.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "" + "" + f.name + "" + "" + f.title + "" + "" + f.company + "" +
           "" + "" + (f.exclude_email == "Yes" ? '' : f.email) + "" + "" + "" + "" + f.comment + "" + "" + ""

```
      $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

 });
```

});

});